# How to get table syntax ( Query ) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Rather than getting table structure (DESC tablename;) Is there any possibility to get table syntax (query) in mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking for this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

This will show you an SQL statement that could be used to create the table schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

You may check out [SHOW CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html)

> Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the named table. To use
>   this statement, you must have some privilege for the table. As of
>   MySQL 5.0.1, this statement also works with views.